# How to produce multistave music using abc notation in a document?

Tags: music, abc

I have been trying to get the package '''abc''' to produce multistave music notation within a document. If possible I'd like to find a solution using this rather than, for instance, LilyPond. After consulting [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/abc/abc.pdf) for the '''abc''' package, I get the impression it should be possible. It reads as follows:

> A recent extension of this language,  called ABC Plus,  allows for
> setting multiple stavesand polyphony. One of the best programs for
> converting these notations into sheet music is '''abcm2ps''', which
> can take an ABC or ABC Plus file and transform it intoa
> PostScript-file. The purpose of this package is to allow LATEX users
> to include in their doc-uments small excerpts of music written
> directly in ABC (Plus).

This is what I've tried:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[generate,ps2eps]{abc} % I've tried different things within the [], but I still suspect the problem lies here... This works for single-stave stuff.
\begin{ducument}

  Here follows three identical renderings of Brother John:
  
  \begin{abc}[name=brother1]
    X:1
    T: Brother John
    L: 1/4
    K: F
    M: 4/4
    V:1
    FGAF | FGAF | ABcz | ABcz | c/d/c/B/ AF | c/d/c/B/ AF |
    V:2
    z4   | z4   | FGAF | FGAF | ABcz        | ABcz        |
  \end{abc}

  \begin{abc}[name=brother2]
    X: 1
    T: Brother John
    L: 1/4
    V: 1 clef=treble name="Soprano" sname="S"
    V: 2 clef=treble name="Contralto" sname="C"
    K: F
    %
    [V:1] FGAF | FGAF | ABcz | ABcz | c/d/c/B/ AF | c/d/c/B/ AF |
    [V:2] z4   | z4   | FGAF | FGAF | ABcz        | ABcz        |
  \end{abc}

  \begin{abc}[name=brother3]
    X: 1
    T: Brother John
    L: 1/4
    K: F 0&2
    %
    z4   & FGAF |z4    & FGAF | FGAF & ABcz | FGAF & ABcz | ABcz & c/d/c/B/ AF | ABcz & c/d/c/B/ AF |
  \end{abc}

\end{ducument}
```

The first two formats follows the suggestions in the [documentation of ABC Plus](http://abcplus.sourceforge.net/abcplus_en.pdf).

The third format [follows ABC2MTEX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/abc2mtex/usrguide.pdf), which I attempted just in case it would work.

I tried to compile this using

```
latex --shell-escape testfile
dvips -o testfile.ps testfile.dvi
ps2pdf testfile.ps
```

This works for single-stave music.

Can one of my three examples be improved in some way, or is there some completely different way of producing multistave sheet music?

Comment: Are you sure the songs are valid `abc` input?

Comment: @egreg I've copied the top two songs from the documentations of ABC Plus, except for shortening them not to make too long an example. The full songs don't compile either. There could very well be some mistake in my '''abc''' code, I'm not an expert abc-er.

Comment: I'm afraid that `abm2ps` has radically changed the way it assigns names to the generated files. I need to study the problem of reading them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure when `abcm2ps` started to append useless numbers to the generated PostScript files, without even any option to turn this feature off. `:-(`

Also, if a title is specified in the `.abc` file, the `-O=` option will use it. `:-(`

Here's a temporary fix.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[generate,ps2eps]{abc}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\abc@parm}{-O\abc@tempfile.ps\space -c}
\define@key{abc}{name}[]{%
  \if!#1!\stepcounter{abc@count}%
    \edef\abc@tempfile{\normalabcoutputfile-\@arabic\c@abc@count}%
  \else
    \def\abc@tempfile{#1001}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  
\begin{abc}[name=brother1]
X: 1
T: Brother John
C: Traditional
L: 1/4
K: F
M: 4/4
V:1
FGAF | FGAF | ABcz | ABcz | c/d/c/B/ AF | c/d/c/B/ AF |
V:2
z4 | z4 | FGAF | FGAF | ABcz | ABcz |
V:1
GCFz |GCFz | z4 | z4 |
V:2
c/d/c/B/ AF | c/d/c/B/ AF | GCFz | GCFz|
\end{abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks! :) I'll wait a bit before accepting, just in case someone finds a smoother solution.